# Command Prompt: Run as other user?

Tags: windows, command-line, runas

If I use the command runas and run a program as a different user on the domain will this actually return information regarding their computer or will it give me my comptuers information?

for example if I use

```
Runas (other user on domain) -tasklist.exe
```

Will this return their tasklist information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this will just run the program locally on your machine with their credentials. I think SysInternals has a program that can execute commands on remote machines - I believe it's called PsExec.

Comment: I have heard of PsExec (but I need to download the toolset), the problem is I need to be able to execute a program on remote machines without downloading/using anything else.

Answer (score 0):

From Powershell you could issue the following command

## Example

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_process | foreach { write-host $_.ProcessName -NoNewline ; Write-Host  $($_.getowner() | select domain, user) }
```

## Sample Output

```
conhost.exe@{domain=LandLocked; user=userA}
iexplore.exe@{domain=LandLocked; user=userB}
iexplore.exe@{domain=LandLocked; user=userB}
chrome.exe@{domain=LandLocked; user=userA}
```